# Vue WebPack Imported Module is not a function

Tags: javascript, laravel, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I have some difficulties with migrating my Vue app to Laravel resources.
So, I have copied every file from a front directory and pasted it in laravel resources/js. And everything seems to look fine, except Auth function.

The error looks like:

> app.js:39856
>
> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: _composable_Auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default(...) is not a function
> at app.js:39856:71
> at app.js:39899:3
> at app.js:39901:12
> ```

My webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.ts('resources/js/app.ts', 'public/js').vue({version: 3}).webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                test: /\.(js|vue|ts)?$/
            },
        ]
    }
});
```

And example how I import the Auth file:

```
//import 
import useAuth from "./composable/Auth";

// define
const { GetCurrentLoggedUser } = useAuth();

//use
GetCurrentLoggedUser();
```

So my Auth.ts file is a bit longer, but I will try to import most of it:

```
import { Ref, ref, computed, ComputedRef } from "vue";
import useCometAPI from "./Api";
import { notify } from "@kyvg/vue3-notification";
import router from "../router";
import { useCookies } from "vue3-cookies";
import { ILogin, User, AuthError } from "./Interfaces/User";
import { useCometApi } from "./Api2";

const cookie = useCookies().cookies;
// the main state holders for the authentication process
const error: Ref<AuthError | null> = ref(null);
const CurrentUser: Ref<User | null> = ref(null);
const CurrentUserCSRF: Ref<string | null> = ref(null);

export default function useAuth() {
    const CurrentUserToken: Ref<string | null> = ref(
        localStorage.getItem("token")
    );

    /**
     * Private method which saves the response in the right state holders
     * @param result
     */
    const _populateReactivity = (result: any): void => {
        CurrentUserToken.value = result?.data.data.token;
        CurrentUser.value = result?.data.data.name;
    };

    const Login = async (payload: ILogin): Promise<void> => {
        await useCometApi()
            .get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie")
            .then(() => {
                useCometApi()
                    .post("/api/auth/login", payload)
                    .then((response: any) => {
                        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.data.token);
                        // cookie.set("token", response.data.data.token);
                        _populateReactivity(response);
                        router.push("/");
                    })
                    .catch((e: any) => {
                        notify({
                            type: "error",
                            title: e.response.data?.message,
                        });
                    });
            });
    };

    const Logout = async (): Promise<void> => {
        useCometApi()
            .delete("/api/auth/logout")
            .then((response: any) => {
                localStorage.removeItem("token");
                // cookie.remove("token");
                CurrentUser.value = null;
                router.push("/");
            })
            .catch((e: any) => {
                notify({
                    type: "error",
                    title: e.response.data?.message,
                });
            });
    };

    /**
     * A Computed property which defines is the current used session has active and logged in the system user.
     *
     * @return ComputedRef<boolean>
     */
    const IsUserLogged: ComputedRef<boolean> = computed(
        () => !!CurrentUser.value
    );

    const GetCurrentLoggedUser = () => {
        useCometApi()
            .get("/api/auth/me")
            .then((result: any) => {
                _populateReactivity(result);
            })
            .catch((e: any) => {
                localStorage.removeItem("token");
                // cookie.remove("token");
                CurrentUserToken.value = null;
                CurrentUser.value = null;
            });
    };

    return {
        CurrentUserToken,
        Login,
        Logout,
        IsUserLogged,
        CurrentUser,
        CurrentUserCSRF,
        error,
        GetCurrentLoggedUser,
    };
}
```

So, all of this works with @vue/cli-service, but it's not using it (I think). Because when the front-end is separated from the backend, everything works fine.
When I remove using Auth, it will work, but the router would break for only one route.

And when I save any file, console break and I have error like:

> [webpack-cli] Error: The loaded module contains errors
> at C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\LoaderPlugin.js:109:11
> at C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1935:5
> at C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\AsyncQueue.js:352:5
> at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10),
> :6:1)
> at AsyncQueue._handleResult (C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\AsyncQueue.js:322:21)
> at C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\AsyncQueue.js:305:11
> at C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1396:15
> at C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:68:3
> at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10),
> :15:1)
> at Cache.store (C:\Users\radei\Projects\KGB-BACKEND\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:107:20)

Any ideas what could be a problem?